# how to install intel HD 4000 ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: intel-hd

i am new to Ubuntu and i want to install the driver of intel hd 4000,any help? i tried a lot of thing but i got missing packages and make problems due to auto make versions mismatch, the graphics driver appears for me is Intel® Ivybridge Mobile and the brightness control doesn't work

Comment: What version of Ubuntu, what machine?  The i915 video driver is present in the default install, and should just work for the HD4000.

Comment: Tell us what "lot of things" mean. Impossible to help otherwise. An HD4000 should work out-of-the-box, though.

Answer (score 2):

In order to install the drivers for your Intel HD 4000. Open Dash go to Software Updater, press the settings... button and go to the Additional Drivers tab, there you can find a list of drivers for your computer simply select the recommended one (if one is recommended) or the lates one.

Comment: That one is empty for me with HD P4600 on 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

It should be usable by default because 14.04 contains all the packages in [the Intel Linux page](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads) but I don't believe 14.04 has the most updated versions. The link will tell you all the packages the Intel graphics drivers depend on.